# Como obter o diretório que o programa está sendo executado?

Tags: c++

Tenho uma aplicação rodando na plataforma Windows. Em um dos meus métodos preciso capturar o diretório onde esta rodando a aplicação, qual a maneira correta de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode estar capturando o diretório usando **_getcwd** .
Pode armazena-lo em uma variável e chamar assim que precisar.
getcwd é uma função POSIX é compilado por todas as plataformas compatíveis com POSIX.
você só vai precisar incluir os cabeçalhos **Unist.d** em **UNIX** e **direct.h** no **Windows**

Um Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef WINDOWS
   #include <direct.h>
   #define Define_CurrentDir _getcwd
#else
   #include <unistd.h>
   #define Define_CurrentDir getcwd
 #endif

        char LOCAL_DIR[FILENAME_MAX];

         if (!Define_CurrentDir(LOCAL_DIR, sizeof(LOCAL_DIR)))
             {
             return errno;
             }

        std::cout << "Diretorio: " << LOCAL_DIR;
```

Answer (score 2):

Para o sistema Windows você pode utilizar a função [`GetModuleFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197.aspx) passando ao parâmetro `hModule` um valor nulo. Algo como isso(não testado):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{   wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH]; 
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH) ;
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    cin.get();

}
```

Outros sistemas operacionais:

- Mac OS X: [`_NSGetExecutablePath()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dyld.3.html)
- Linux: [`readlink /proc/self/exe`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html)
- Solaris: [`getexecname()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5168/6mbb3hrb1/index.html)
- FreeBSD: se tiver o [`procfs`](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/pt_BR.ISO8859-1/articles/linux-users/procfs.html) pode usar `readlink /proc/curproc/file` - FreeBSD não tem `procfs` por padrão. Uma outro modo é usar a função [`getprogname()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getprogname&sektion=3) em conjunto com outra função, [`realpath()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html).

Referências: [Fonte¹](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024937/1608936) e [Fonte²](http://www.lemoda.net/c/exe-path/)